# How should I include files from outside of document root?

Tags: php, linux, hosting

I wanted to include `pear/Mail.php`.
 I asked the hosting support to provide me the path, It is `"/usr/local/php-5.3.17/share/pear/"`.
But it doesn't work independently or from document root, and it seems I can't access upper level directories by using `"../"`.

There are two parent folder for the document root: `/home/www/`

Answer (score 2):

you have two way

1) by including in php.ini

like

```
 ; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
 ;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
 ;window
 include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;C:\wamp\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library"
```

2)add pear directory as valid directory in Apache Config like

```
 <Directory "/usr/share/rrdtool/fonts/">
    Options All
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't customize php.ini because my account is free, I think i don't access to home directory either, It should be better to contact the hosting support again. thanks anyway

Comment: @csstd use `ini_set(string $option, string $value);`

Answer (score 0):

after recontacting the support team they stated that the error

> require_once(/usr/local/php-5.3.17/share/pear/Mail.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in ...

is due to SMTP outgoing server connections are disabled.

Answer (score -1):

```
include '/usr/local/php-5.3.17/share/pear/Mail.php';
```